# delete derby tables when program ends

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I'm using in-memory derby db for my java application. I would like to delete all the tables/databases it created once the application ends. So when it starts back up, I want it to start fresh.

Comment: i know i can add delete statements at the end of the class...i was wondering if there was a setting that i could turn on/off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you application uses only a single database connection, then [derby global temporary tables](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html) would provide what you need.